# Excel create "bars" or fill series of cells based on other cell value

Tags: excel, vba, function, cells

I want to create a automatically generated "timeline" as i fill a column with numbers. Lets say C4 gets the value of 5. Then I want D4:I4 to be either filled with a 1 (so I can use conditional formatting), or filled with a specific color. This should be the case for more than 300 rows, C4:C350. Is there a way to use normal formulas or do I need to write a macro. I need it to be as easily used as possible since a lot of people not used to work with macros should be able to use it.

A         B     C       D  E F G H I J K L 
Art no1  Name1  Amount  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
Art no2  Name2  Amount  1 2 3 4 5
Art no2  Name2  Amount  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

- Select the range you want to be colored, i.e. D4:M350. M depends on the max value your column C will have. In this example, I assumed that 10 will be the max value (D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M = 10 columns).
- On the Home tab, click Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Format values where this formula is true
- Enter this formula:

  ```
  =COLUMN(D4)-COLUMN($C4)<=$C4
  ```
- Click the Format button, choose your desired cell format and you're good to go.